# Working with ancestors in GAE

Tags: python, google-app-engine, app-engine-ndb

I only want that someone confirm me that I'm doing things in the right way.

I have this structure: Books that have Chapters (ancestor=Book) that have Pages (ancestor=Chapter)

It is clear for me that, to search for a Chapter by ID, I need the book to search by ancestor query.

My doubt is: do I need all the chain book-chapter to search a page?

For example (I'm in NDB):

```
class Book(ndb.Model):
    # Search by id
    @classmethod
    def by_id(cls, id):
        return Book.get_by_id(long(id))

class Chapter(ndb.Model):
    # Search by id
    @classmethod
    def by_id(cls, id, book):
        return Chapter.get_by_id(long(id), parent=book.key)

class Page(ndb.Model):
    # Search by id
    @classmethod
    def by_id(cls, id, chapter):
        return Page.get_by_id(long(id), parent=chapter.key)
```

Actually, when I need to search a Page to display its contents, I'm passing the complete chain in the url like this:

getPage?bookId=5901353784180736&chapterId=5655612935372800&pageId=1132165198169

So, in the controller, I make this:

```
def get(self):
    # Get the id parameters
    bookId = self.request.get('bookId')
    chapterId = self.request.get('chapterId')
    pageId = self.request.get('pageId')

    if bookId and chapterId and pageId:
        # Must be a digit
        if bookId.isdigit() and chapterId.isdigit() and pageId.isdigit():
            # Get the book
            book = Book.by_id(bookId)

            if book:
                # Get the chapter
                chapter = Chapter.by_id(chapterId, book)

                if chapter:
                    # Get the page
                    page = Page.by_id(pageId, chapter)
```

Is this the right way? Must I have always the complete chain in the URL to get the final element of the chain?

If this is right, I suppose that this way of work, using NDB, does not have any impact on the datastore, because repeated calls to this page always hit the NDB cache for the same book, chapter and page (because I'm getting by id, is not a fetch command). Is my suppose correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there's no need to do that. The point is that keys are paths: you can build them up dynamically and only hit the datastore when you have a complete one. In your case, it's something like this:

```
page_key = ndb.Key(Book, bookId, Chapter, chapterId, Page, pageId)
page = page_key.get()
```

See [the NDB docs](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/entities) for more examples.

Comment: Ummm, so I still need to save all the chain in the URL through every page request, but I can reduce the 3 calls to database to only 1. Is this? I've readed the docs before, but are not so clear for me in terms of the use of Keys (maybe I don't understand it well). Finally, do you think I must change my by_id method to use directly the bookId instead passing the book instance? Thanks for you response.

Comment: If you don't want to pass the entire chain separately in the URL, you can use `page_key.urlsafe()` which encodes the whole thing into one (long) string.

Comment: And I don't understand your question about the by_id methods: although I must say I don't understand the point of the by_id methods at all, since they just call get_by_id which you could just as easily do directly.

Comment: I've tested your solution, but is not working, not chapter found using this key format, even using this: `chapter_key = ndb.Key(Book, bookId, parent=ndb.Key(Chapter, chapterId))`. Regardless this, about URL, for me is not a problem to pass all IDs, this let me easy access to search a especific book or chapter if needed, but urlsafe() will give me full access to book or chapter also, or only to the page itself?

Comment: About by_id, it is just because of that: maybe I'm doing the search by id bad and, to change the way to do it in all the program, I only need to do it in the class method, not in all the program code.

Comment: You still have to use the *complete* path. And book is the parent of chapter, not the other way round.

Comment: Umm, I'm missing something here which is making that your solution don't work. Note that my `bookId` corresponds to `book.key.id()` entity. When I save an entity, I'm not assigning any key, I'm letting datastore to auto assign one (I think this is correct).

Comment: sorry, any of this works: `chapter_key = ndb.Key(Chapter, chapterId, parent=ndb.Key(Book, bookId))` nor `chapter_key = ndb.Key(Book, bookId, Chapter, chapterId)`

Comment: Ok, I've found the problem. Using the interactive console I found that this is what I have saved as chapter: `Chapter(key=Key('Book', 5901353784180736, 'Chapter', 5655612935372800), blah, blah...` but using only `chapter_key = ndb.Key(Book, bookId, Chapter, chapterId)` the result is `chapter_key = Key('Book', '5901353784180736', 'Chapter', '5655612935372800')` so I did `chapter_key = ndb.Key('Book', long(bookId), 'Chapter', long(chapterId))` and the result was that it worked. Is this right or must I change the way I save the keys (actually I'm saving `book.key.id()` as parent)